# dynamic data extraction using scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm really new to python and scrapy and currently trying to implement a spider to obtain certain information from a website.
The website has a dynamic flow of data (current prices which change every couple of seconds).
When I try to extract it using `response.xpath(...).extract()` I get the variable name instead of the current value which I need.

here is the code:

```
class DataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "data"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "the website.com"
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.xpath('...').extract())
```

now when I run it from the cmd, I get this when printed:

```
['{{t.price | number:currentProduct.priceTick}}']
```

My question is how can I obtain the real current value?

Tnx!

Comment: Seems like your site uses angular or something. You will need to use Scrapy splash with Scrapy to extract data from such a site, since it needs javascript and won't work normally

Comment: I tried everything to install Docker on my windows 10 home, couldn't manage to accomplish it (various issues). Do you know any other way? perhaps how to use Splash without Docker (couldn't find how), or using some other technique?

Comment: Get docker toolbox and do it using that. Docker will make things a lot easier for you.

Comment: I installed it and ran into different issues which I could not resolve, no matter what I tried. Searched on google everywhere :(